# Find norm of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have to check if those operators are bounded and if so what are their norms.

> 1) $\phi:C^1[0,1]\ni f
> > \rightarrow\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt+f'(2/3)\in\mathbb{R}$ with norm
>   $\|\cdot\|=\sup_t|f(t)|+\sup_t|f'(t)|$

**My attempt**

Its obvious that $|\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt+f'(2/3)|\le \sup_t|f(t)|+\sup_t|f'(t)|$. So $\|\phi\|\le1$ but I cant prove it can't be $<1$.

> 2) $\theta:\ell^2\ni (x_n) \rightarrow \sum_{n=2011}^{\infty}2^{-n}x_{3n} + \sum_{n=2012}^{\infty}3^{-n}x_{3n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt**

I can prove it is continuous (using Cauchy-Schwarz) but can't find the norm.

Comment: for the first one the norm turns out to be $1$. imagine a function which is $0$ far away from $2/3$ but has a sudden jump near $2/3$ (so that derivative there is big) but on an interval short enough so that the function itself doesn't grow too much, something like 
$$ f(t) := \int_0^t \chi_{[2/3-1/n, 2/3+1/n]}(x) - \chi_{[2/3 +2/n, 2/3 +3/n]}(x)dx$$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. this one is not differentiable everywhere so you just need to fix that, try to think how.

Comment: I thought of almost the same example but dont know how formally can I write this

Comment: well, you need to integrate a nicer function that is nevertheless close to what I gave. hint - can be piecewise linear